# Negation of gsub | Replace everything except strings in a certain vector

Tags: r, regex, gsub, negation

I have a vector of strings:

```
ve <- c("N","A","A","A","N","ANN","NA","NFNFNAA","23","N","A","NN", "parnot", "important", "notall")
```

I want to keep only three possible values in this vector: `N`, `A`, and `NA`.

Therefore, I want to replace any element that is NOT `N` or `A` with `NA`.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following:

```
gsub(ve, pattern = '[^NA]+', replacement = 'NA')
gsub(ve, pattern = '[^N|^A]+', replacement = 'NA')
```

But these don't work well, because they replace every instance of "A" or "N" in every string with NA. So in some cases I end up with `NANANANANANA`, instead of simply `NA`.

Comment: Try with `%in%` i.e. `ve[!ve %in% c("A", "N", "NA")] <- 'NA'`

Comment: @akrun Brilliant approach. Deserves to be answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are looking for fixed matches, then use `%in%` with negation `!` and assign it to `'NA'`

```
ve[!ve %in% c("A", "N", "NA")] <- 'NA'
```

Note that in `R`, missing value is unquoted `NA` and not quoted.  Hope it is a different category and would advise to change the category name to different name to avoid future confusions while parsing

Comment: I am accepting this one as the correct answer because it is a very simple and straight-forward approach/solution to an elementary problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use negative lookahead assertion.

```
ve <- c("N","A","A","A","N","ANN","NA","NFNFNAA","23","N","A","NN", "parnot", "important", "notall")
sub("^(?![NA]$).*", "NA", ve, perl=T)
# [1] "N"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "N"  "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" "N"  "A"  "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA"
```

`^(?![NA]$)` asserts that

-> after the start `^` there should be only one letter `[NA]` either `N` or `A` which should be followed by line end `$`.

`.*` match all chars

So that above regex would match any string except the string is `N` or `A`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative regex solution

```
ve[!grepl("^[N|A]$", ve)] <- NA_character_
```

You still probably should go with Akrun's solution.